# Get word frequency rankings of words in postgreSQL and filter by label

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgreSQL database with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
created_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
tweet TEXT,
label INT);
```

The following data is inserted:

```
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'foo foo squared', 1);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'foo fox squared', 1);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'foo bar', 3);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'raven bar', 2);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-17 00:00:00+00', 'bar standard', 1);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-17 00:00:00+00', 'bar none', 2);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-17 00:00:00+00', 'bar', 1);
```

I have the following query that fetches the frequency of each word in the table and ranks them, grouping by day:

```
select *
from (
    select date_trunc('day', created_at) as created_day, word, count(*) as cnt,
        rank() over(partition by date_trunc('day', created_at) order by count(*) desc) rn
    from dummy d
    cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(
        trim(regexp_replace(tweet, '\y(rt|co|https|amp|none)\y', '', 'g')),
        '\s+'
    ) w(word)
    group by created_day, word
) t
where (created_day > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10 days') 
    and word IS NOT NULL
order by created_day DESC, rn;
```

Result:

```
      created_day       |   word   | cnt | rn
------------------------+----------+-----+----
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | foo      |   4 |  1
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | bar      |   2 |  2
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | squared  |   2 |  2
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | raven    |   1 |  4
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | fox      |   1 |  4
 2020-12-17 00:00:00+00 | bar      |   3 |  1
 2020-12-17 00:00:00+00 | standard |   1 |  2
```

I would like to group by the label so that the new query shows the word rankings filtered by label like so:

```
      created_day       |   word   | cnt | rn | label |
------------------------+----------+-----+--------------
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | foo      |   3 |  1 |     1 |
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | squared  |   2 |  2 |     1 |
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | fox      |   1 |  3 |     1 |
 2020-12-17 00:00:00+00 | bar      |   2 |  1 |     1 |
 2020-12-17 00:00:00+00 | standard |   1 |  2 |     1 |
```

I've tried adding a WHERE clause to filter by predictions:

```
where (created_day > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10 days')
    and word IS NOT NULL
    and label = 1
order by created_day DESC, rn;
```

But I get the error `column "label" does not exist`.

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: why `prediction` since you got no column with that name at all?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `label`. Will edit now

Comment: You are not selecting `label` in the sub query, so you cannot access it in the main query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner when I add it to the select clause in the subquery, I get the error: ` column "d.label" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: also the problem is `foo` appear in mutiple label, how can you decide where he is? because if you `group by` label you will get three different `foo` and make the rank and count useless.

Comment: just add the `label` in `group by created_day, word, label` but the data will not be what expect output show us.

Comment: Okay, so if foo appears three times in label 1 tweets and twice in lable 2 tweets, you want to show foo twice in your results, once for label 1, once for label 2, but both with the same count of five and both with the same ranking?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner also the date my friend... the origin query also include date... this  just doesn't add up in OP expect output unless he explain clearly to us.

Comment: Yep, that's true. @mehsheenman: Please explain how or if a label affects the count and ranking and please edit your sample result. 'fox' does not appear in your label 1 tweets, but you are showing 'fox' for label 1 in your results.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner if foo appears three times in label 1, then it would be counted as +1 in the cnt column - there wouldn't be another row for foo for that day.

Comment: @T.Peter Apologies, I updated the post to better reflect what I'm looking for

Comment: On 2020-12-18 there is a total of 3 'foo' of which 2 belong to label 1. You show the total count of 3. On 2020-12-17 there is a total of 3 'bar' of which 2 belong to label 1. You show the subtotal count of 2. Why do you show the overall total for 'foo', but the label 1 subtotal for 'bar'? I suppose one is correct, the other is incorrect? So, which of the two is correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the overall count was correct. For the purpose of showing the rankings, I made another re-edit and added another foo to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new result shows you want to count and rank per day, word **and label**. This means you just have to add `label` to your `GROUP BY` and `PARTITION BY` clauses (and probably to `ORDER BY`, too).

```
select *
from 
(
  select 
    date_trunc('day', created_at) as created_day, 
    word, 
    label, 
    count(*) as cnt,
    rank() over(partition by date_trunc('day', created_at), label order by count(*) desc) as rn
  from dummy d
  cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table
  (
    trim(regexp_replace(tweet, '\y(rt|co|https|amp|none)\y', '', 'g')),
    '\s+'
  ) w(word)
  group by created_day, word, label
) t
where (created_day > current_date - interval '10 days') and word is not null
order by created_day desc, label, rn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `min(label)` , this get the expect output but OP might need to be more clarify about the problem mention in comment.

```
select *
from (
    select date_trunc('day', created_at) as created_day, word, count(*) as cnt,
        rank() over(partition by date_trunc('day', created_at) order by count(*) desc) rn,
        min(label) as label
    from dummy d 
    cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(
        trim(regexp_replace(tweet, '\y(rt|co|https|amp|none)\y', '', 'g')),
        '\s+'
    ) w(word)
    group by created_day, word
) t
where (created_day > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10 days') 
    and word IS NOT NULL
    and label = 1
order by created_day DESC, rn;
```

also the number in expect output is weird in some row so some row is a little different from expect output but I do count the data by eye to make sure the data in db<>fiddle is right so maybe OP can also point those out.

here is
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=abc603484d8693bdb6d9f9d41af0a76e)